# Can I ask a moderator to delete my question?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question and it seemed simple or even "unclear what you're asking" for many users with high reputation. I just wanted to understand something that I did not know before and finally I received the answer to my question.

Up till now, I have received 8 down-votes on this question and it decreased my reputation.

So now I would like to delete this question but I can't since there are answers with up-votes there and I can't delete this question since "others invested time and effort on it" so does SO have pity about people answering questions but not about the persons asking the question?

Can I ask a moderator to delete it so I will get my score back?

Comment: .. please, don't just go downvoting the question more, people!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier thanks. As you can see people are not nice. Not at all.

Comment: It seems that the best thing you can do at this point is to edit your post to make it a better question.

Comment: @Eliyahu A downvote is not "not nice". Downvotes are nice because they allow posts to be ranked. Your question is possibly bad, it's just not necessary for it to be mentioned here. The attention it would gain is "artificial", and as such, lessens the real value of the score.

Comment: @Eliyahu it's a bad question.  Bad questions tend to get downvoted.  It's rude and unwelcoming to ask for special treatment for your bad question when the hundreds of other bad questions collect downvotes.  The only reason I have not downvoted it too is that I've made this comment and try to avoid the meta-effect.

Comment: But I had a question. I did not find any similar question here so I could learn about my problem before asking this question

Comment: @MartinJames while that is all true you sometimes wonder if some down voters are only able to find bad questions when pointed out in a meta post ... as if they never heard of PHP. Andriod or RegEx...

Comment: I mean, you have 1783 rep?  So you asked a bad question and got downvoted a lot, does it really matter so much?  Just carry on asking some good questions and provide good answers, as you have been doing to accumulate your ~1.8k rep, and get your imaginary internet points back again:)

Comment: @rene well, as I commented, I avoid the meta effect.  If I comment, or otherwise refernce a post here on meta, I don't generally downvote it after.  A question would have to be so terribad for me to go meta-effect on it that it would probably be closed/deleted as R/A anyway.

Comment: @rene 'as if they never heard of PHP. Andriod or RegEx' - well, now that you mention it.. if only.... :)

Comment: @Eliyahu it happens to us all.  Here's another example of a brain-dead moment where the OP asked about a terribad design and got hammered for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511860/can-a-dynamically-allocated-shared-ptr-delete-itself-via-the-dtor-of-the-object  Just move on:)

Comment: @Eliyahu yeah the meta effect is a strange beast.... See it as a spotlight. You went in front of the meta crew, and put your post up. That'll mean more eyes on it. Since these eyes are the most quality minded ones around the site, your question will get more votes (up or down) than it would have otherwise. There is nothing mean about it...

Answer (score 4):

It didn't decrease your score very much (16 reputation points iirc, which is almost exactly 1% of your current reputation).

People shouldn't be downvoting "simple" questions (but they sometimes do).  They should (and do) downvote poor questions.

You need to remember that the *point* of Stack Overflow is to generate a searchable database of Questions and (good) Answers.  In reality, questions are ten a penny, but good answers are rare; therefor SO prioritizes the people answering the questions.

Your fix is to answer some other questions yourself (or ask a good question).  Alternatively, you can propose edits to improve questions; if these are accepted, you earn a little rep.

Comment: After 9 downwotes (thanks to to "good" guys) editing will not help there.

Comment: I meant "edit other questions" - you can get some rep from that.  You don't "propose" edits to your own question - you just make that.  I will clarify.

Comment: Editing your existing question or answers also bump up your question.

Comment: @Eliyahu 'thanks to to "good" guys' snarky, unwelcome, rude, abusive and you would risk being suspended for it were it on the main site.  Nearly as unwelcome as an OP asserting that their bad question deserves different treatment than other bad questions.

Comment: (1) simple questions are almost always duplicate. (2) on the other hand, some of them get a looot of upvotes from HNQ, so on average that's expected.